# Creating Materials to Scale from image?

Tags: materials

Firstly, I'm using blender 2.8 and the cycles rendering engine.

I work for a company what sells PVC bathroom paneling and want to create a bathroom with these panels on the walls...

I have images of all of our wall panels to a scaled size (1m wide to 2.7m height)

I was wanting to create an image based texture on blender which would use these images as a scaled reference (So if the material is applied on a 2.4m standard wall it will not squash it down) likewise, if it is applied on a 5m wall, it will repeat 5 times and not stretch it.

I'm sure previously in Maya i've seen that you can actually define a material size.

How would this be achieved in blender?

This will be a base material which i will then add the diffuse and gloss textures to accordingly to show the reflectivity or the non reflectivity of these panels.

Kind Regards

Andy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just connect mapping node and texture co-ordinate node to your image texture as shown in screenshot below and scale the texture to your desired size
[image: Texture cordinate and mapping node]

Comment: This isn't true to scale, since it depends on the UV.

Comment: Thanks, this is great!... Do you know if it's possible to kind of push the repeat into each other so they lap by a very very small amount?